# How do I reuse the connection string throughout my application once it has been fetched from the AppConfig file?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have this code in several repository classes and I keep recalling the method `GetConnectionString()`.  Basically, I want to call `GetConnectionString()` once and have the variable `ConnectionString` available to all of my repository classes, reusing the variable once it is fetched. How do I do this?

```
public class OrganizationRepository
{
    string ConnectionString;
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string strReturn = string.Empty;
        strReturn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyTeamScoresDB"].ConnectionString;
        return strReturn;
    }
  ....
 }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `public static` ??

Comment: I second what @Nithish Inpursuit Ofhappiness has commented about static classes. I just dont fancy inheritance for such a scenario + You could also consider Dependency Injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the connection string to any class that needs it.

Though, the only classes that should need one are the repository classes.

Only way to achieve reuse here is to have a `RepositoryBase` where you get the connection string and all repositories inherit from and therefore have access to it.

```
public class RepositoryBase
{
    private string connectionString;
    public static string RepositoryBase()
    {
        connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyTeamScoresDB"].ConnectionString;
    }

    protected string ConnectionString
    {
       get { return connectionString;}
    }
  ....
}

public class OrganizationRepository : RepositoryBase
{
    // Can use the ConnectionString property of the base class
}
```

Comment: How would RepositoryBase get executed once? I am not sure that I understand.  The inheritance would give me the method in every repository, but I would still have to call the GetConnectionStringMethod over and over again, wouldn't I?

Comment: @AllenB - Well, if you have a read-only, protected `ConnectionString` string property, once you set it in the base class constructor, you just need to call it in the inheriting types.

Comment: Can you point me to or provide some code that illustrates this? I think I understand how that would allow any Repository to set the value, but still a little unclear on how to get the execution to occur.  I believe that this is the answer. I just need to see it to understand.  Thank you.

Comment: I think that I see this.  Will I reference this property like this RepositoryBase.ConnectionString?

Comment: Um. You have direct access to it from inheriting classes. You just call `ConnectionString`.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration manager class already provides caching, so calling the ConnectionStrings propery multiple times does not cause any overhead. 
Further I suggest you create an abstract base repository class where you manage the connection string

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public class MyConfiguration{

     private static string myConnString;

     public static string MyConnectionString
     {
         get{
               if(myConnString == null){
                    myConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyTeamScoresDB"].ConnectionString;
               }
               return myConnString;
         }
     } 
}
```

It will iniitialize the connection string for the first time when it is requested and then just reuses the value.